# Java generic method is holding two different type of values

Tags: java

I am learning Java *generics* and tried the below code

```
class A {

    public <T> void pick(T a, T b){
        System.out.println(b.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());
    }
}

    new A().pick("abc", 5);
```

Here my idea is that `pick` function's parameter should be of same type as both are `T`.

However when I am calling it using `new A().pick("abc",5)` there are no compile time error.

Rather I get the result `b is Integer class` and `a is String class`

Can any one help me with this concept.

Comment: There is no need for a compiler error as long as there is a type for `T` that is a common type of String and Integer.

Comment: In this case `T` is `Object`.

Comment: Similar question (for arrays, but that difference is not important): [Single generic parameter accepts two different types at the same time](//stackoverflow.com/q/14183170)

Comment: Thank you guys, I think I need to study more ..:) :)

Comment: @Joe : Thank you, it was linked in the above comment as well. Yes its kind a explains but the below accepted answer is more precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify any bounds for your generic type. In this case, `T` will fall back to `Object`. You won't get any compiler errors as this is perfectly valid.

You probably want to do something like

```java
class A {

    public <T extends SomeClass> void pick(T a, T b){
        System.out.println(b.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Checkout [Bounded Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) or [Bounded Types with Generics in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bounded-types-generics-java/)

Comment: Thank you @Sakibul , it is I was looking for and clear my concept also .. Thank you

Comment: one more thing - Ideally, I am support to call pick function like this `new A().<String>pick("abc","5") , it is right otherwise the way I have called it is raw type

Comment: yes. you can call it that way. But the compiler is smart enough to infer the type most of the time. In this case, since both arguments are `String`s, the compiler would know the `T` is a `String`, so you can do `new A().pick("abc","5")`

Comment: Above comment also makes sense .. Anyways thank you very much